# autofit table header width as text in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

how can I make the table header width that fits only text? Means table      column header width varies as name of the columns.

Comment: Use the `TableHeader`'s `TableCellRenderer` for each column and calculate the preferred size, using the width to set the size of the `TableColumn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/). You can set the width of each TableColumn to be based on the text:

1. in the header
2. in the row data
3. in the header and the row data

Comment: thanks a lot, that link worked perfectly as i needed, i am thankful by heart.